# If has action not working as expected

Tags: functions, actions

I'm using [ACF Blocks](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks) in a theme I'm building.

Here's my block template file within /my-plugin/template-parts/blocks/page-intro/page-intro.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Page Intro Block Template.
 *
 * @param   array $block The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content The block inner HTML (empty).
 * @param   bool $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 * @param   (int|string) $post_id The post ID this block is saved to.
 */
?>
<?php do_action('acf_add_class'); ?>
<div class="page-intro-wrapper" style="background: url(<?php esc_url( the_field('background_image') ); ?> )">
    <div class="page-intro">
        <h2><?= esc_html( get_field('title') ); ?></h2>
        <?= get_field('text'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll see that I've added `<?php do_action('acf_add_class'); ?>` at the top.

I then have the following via my plugin:

```
/**
 * Add custom classes to body
 */
function body_classes( $classes ) {
    
    if ( has_action('acf_add_class') ) {
        $classes[] = 'page-intro';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_classes' );
```

I was hoping that `if ( has_action('acf_add_class') ) {` would trigger the condition and add the class, but this hasn't worked.

I've also tried this within the `body_class` filter:

```
if ( has_action('acf_add_class', get_queried_object_id() ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'page-intro';
}
```

This question may be off-topic if the issue is ACF related.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hasn't the `body_class` already been output by this point? It's too late, time travel would be necessary for this code to work as expected. Chances are `body_class` already has something you can latch on to for this, otherwise you should have asked about your original problem of how to add a class to the body tag using the `body_class` in a particular scenario, rather than how to fix a proposed solution. How do the templates know to load `page-intro.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what `has_action` does. `has_action` is true, if functions are added to fire on that hook. It is not a way to detect `do_action` calls.

However in that code:

- Nothing was added to the `acf_add_class` action
- If something had been added, it still wouldn't work because the `body_class` filter has already ran. It would either need the ability to see into the future to observe that a filter was added to that hook in `page-intro.php`, or `page-intro.php` would need to make changes several microseconds into the past.

Fundamentally, this approach cannot work because the body class has already been generated and sent to the browser. It cannot be fixed, a brand new solution is necessary

Comment: Thanks, Tom. You make some excellent points. I'll explore some different options.